# How to specify multiple Callback URLs for Autodesk Forge App?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, callbackurl

> "You can register more than one callback URL."

is said in Callback URL tooltip.

But there is no example on how to enter multiple URLs.

What is the correct separator?

I've tried ";", "\n".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typo on the tooltip and we will fix it.

Today you can use *

**Update Sep 2022**

This feature is now available!

Comment: This means in my case, that I have to register 3 apps. One for every stage: 1. `https://my-app.dev.otc.test.com/callback/forge` 2. `https://my-app.otc.test.com/callback/forg` 3. `http://localhost:8080/callback/forge`

Comment: you can use * for 1 and 2, but it’s better to have different IDs for different environments, prevents data loss

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves I'm having the same problem, using `*` doesn't solve it. What separator can we use to specify different URLs with different domains? Also, the tooltip still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth trying without a separator.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

you want to set the callback URL as

```
*.myapp.com
```

and we can use it

```
dev.myapp.com
test.myapp.com
any.myapp.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the tooltip says it's possible, I got confirmation from AutoDesk's support that multiple URLs as in different hostnames is not supported currently. It is supposed to come in the next couple of months though.

If the hostname is only one, you can add `*` as a wildcard to support multiple routes and query strings.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry to post this as an answer but S.O. won't let me comment; brilliant system.)

@Edson posted above that this (as of his answer in February) is not actually possible yet, but would be coming in a couple months. Anyone know if this actually has been fixed/supported? (Not holding my breath...)

Also, is the wildcard the only option? My paths do not all match a simple pattern.
e.g.

```
local.myapp.com
www.myapp.com
staging.myapp.com/stagingDev
staging.myapp.com/stagingQA
```

I have to say, when I did the exact same thing with Procore, it was so much easier. They have a simple text box (instead of a single line) and you just enter as many entries as you need.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

As of 1st September 2022 it is possible now to add multiple Callback URLs:
[image]