# Autodesk Forge App config; how to set multiple callbacks?

Tags: oauth-2.0, callback, autodesk-forge

I have a new Forge App and it works for retrieving OAuth token for the one configured site (local, currently). Their documentation says that you can configure multiple callbacks for an app, but I only saw room for the one, and there were no examples. Can I just list them all separated by semicolons, or other punctuation?

When I did this exact same thing with configuring a Procore App, they had a text box and it was clear and easy to enter multiple callback locations. Forge, not so much.

Thanks in advance!

I have not experimented with trying to add multiple callbacks on one line because those environments are not ready yet for testing (but I would prefer to know the correct technique before proceeding!)

Comment: This question has been already answered here : [How-to-specify-multiple-callback-urls-for-autodesk-forge-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014486/how-to-specify-multiple-callback-urls-for-autodesk-forge-app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify multiple Callback URLs for Autodesk Forge App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014486/how-to-specify-multiple-callback-urls-for-autodesk-forge-app)

Comment: Thanks, that was my exact question, I swear I searched before I posted. Unfortunately it doesn't entirely solve the issue because either (1) it isn't implemented yet and/or (2) the implementation (as I understand it) doesn't fulfill my needs.